# Input variable amounts of data with no termination character C++

Tags: c++, input, operator-overloading

I'm having trouble properly overload the input operator to allow for variable amounts of data to be input by the user. The object is a polynomial array that holds coefficients under the index of their degree. So if the input is `5 6 2 3 1 4 -3`, 5 is stored at index 6, 2 at 3, 1 at 4, and -3 at 0. I have a set_ceoff() function that inserts and resizes if necessary, but our instructor specifically asked not to require a termination character to read the input. So far, this is the code that I have, based on information I found on the internet, and it worked when I coded it, then I came back to the code a few days later and now it just breaks after I input the same data I used before. (this is a few days after I finished and submitted the assignment with confidence... so now I'm panicking a bit :S)

Here is my overloaded >> operator:

```
friend istream& operator >>(istream& input, Polynomial& arr) {
    // variables to hold input values
    int coeff = 0;
    int power = 0;
    // read input, inserting values into poly and power, then into arr, if 
    // successful
    while (true) {
        if (input >> coeff) {
            if (input >> power) {
                arr.set_coeff(coeff, power);
            }
            else {
                arr.set_coeff(coeff, 0);
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

Any help is appreciated and I don't expect an answer, but a point in the right direction would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Define "breaks". As in a sequence you believe used to work no longer does and the code is "broken" somehow? Or it hits the `break;` prematurely (or successfully)?

Comment: For me, it works alright (i made set_coeff push a new expression onto a vector), except I have to enter another non-numerical character and press enter before it registers.

Comment: You're idea looks correct. Slightly modified to use a `std::map<int,int>` since I don't have your poly class (and as a bonus accumulates like-exponents and eliminates ones with zero-coefficients), [See it live](http://ideone.com/F2IW1l).

Comment: Your code works as long as you end the input such as Control-D in Unix. `echo '5 6 2 3 4 1 -3' | ./polynomial` runs fine for instance. You can also run polynomial and enter the numbers with arbitrary new lines. You just have to remember to Control-D at the end to get the program to process the input. Your while loop has no end until the `input` object is closed or returns EOF.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! It seems I misunderstood the instructions and the first value of input is the number of integers that will precede it, so it was a easy fix :)

Answer (score 0):

I misread the instructions, the first value of input is the number of integers that will come after it, so I grabbed the first value and looped that many times through the input to grab the rest.

```
int nums = 0;
int value = 0;

input >> nums;

for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
    input >> value;
    pArray.set_coeff(i,value);
}
```

Thanks for all the help and sorry for the mixup!